# JPA Specification - search simultaneously in main table rows and child rows with relation OneToMany

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have two entities. One of them is a child of the other one with a relation with OneToMany. Is it possible to implement search criteria that looks up simultaneously in both the main entity and all the child entities?

Example: I have a Company with many employees. If I search with some text, I want to retrieve all the companies, which title contains that text or its employee's names contain that text.

Here are the example entities:

```
@Entity
public class Company extends AbstractEntity {
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String uuid;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String companyName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = “company”, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    protected Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
public class Employee extends AbstractEntity {
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String uuid;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = “company_id”, nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Company company;
}
```

Here is the example query, that I want to transform into Specification criteria

```
@Query(value = “SELECT DISTINCT c from Company c left outer join c.employees e 
            WHERE c.companyName LIKE CONCAT('%',:text,'%') 
              or e.firstName  LIKE CONCAT('%',:text,'%')  
              or  e.lastName  LIKE CONCAT('%',:text,'%')”)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring JPA data repository, your interface method would look like this.

```
Company findByCompanyNameConatainingOrEmployeesFirstNameConatainingOrEmployeeslastNameConataining(String searchTextCompanyTitle, String searchTextEmployeeFName, String searchTextEmployeeLName);
```

If you are not using data repository, please explain your data access design to get an accurate answer.